# Match string using regex in C language (ignore case-sensitivity)

Tags: c, regex

This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[]= "Michael Corleone";
    char inputName[40];

    regex_t regex;
    int return_value;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(inputName, sizeof(inputName), stdin);
    // Remove new line from fgets
    inputName[strcspn(inputName, "\n")] = 0;
    
    // Regcomp string input by user as pattern
    return_value = regcomp(&regex, inputName, 0);
    // Regexec string that will match against user input
    return_value = regexec(&regex, name, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (return_value == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
        printf("Pattern not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
}
```

I try to match a string using regex. As you can see, my code works pretty well. There's a person store in array named **Michael Corleone**. Then, when user try to input: **Michael** or **Corleone** or **Michael Corleone** it will matched and print the full name!

But the problem is case-sensitivity. If user try to input those name in **lowercase** it will failed.

I try to use this inside `regcomp`: `regcomp(&regex, "[a-zA-Z][inputName]", 0);` It works when i try to type the name in lowercase. But then i found out, it also works when i type another name like **John**, **Leon**, or **Angel**. So, i think it match everything that is alphabets.

Do you guys have the solution, please? Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace the last argument to `regcomp` function (which is `0` now) with `REG_ICASE`:

```c
return_value = regcomp(&regex, inputName, REG_ICASE); // 0 replaced with REG_ICASE
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/ooxE5L).

From the [`regcomp` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp):

> **`REG_ICASE`**
> Do not differentiate case. Subsequent `regexec()` searches using this pattern buffer will be case insensitive.